# How to make snap to top of div

Tags: html, css

I want the text to be perfectly aligned to the picture. But the text has some room on each side. This is supposed to be shown on different devices so just hardcoding like top : -3 px won't work.

Is there any way to make the text snap to the top of the div.

The blue area is the selection overlay that shows the div when I hover over the html element chrome inspect:

[image: Image from chrome]

```
<div class="content-with-padding">
<img src="http://www.slu.se/Global/externwebben/overgripande-slu-bilder/utbildning-bilder/SLU-Karriar/logos/logo_forb_tria.gif" />
<span>
    <div class="medium-title">Title</div>
    <div class="small-text">Some text</div>
</span>
```

```
.medium-title {
  font-size: 17px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.small-text {
  font-size: 14px;

}

img {
  float: left;  
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fx314qhh/

Comment: Could you please share a fiddle with us..

Comment: Hi, be sure to include relevant code to recreate the situation, to better aid people here in answering your question.

Comment: Try to change the `line-height` attribute of text, also make sure text do not have any `margin` and `padding` set.

Comment: Do you have any code? Have you tried with line-height?

Comment: try `vertical-align:middle;`

Answer (score 0):

`top:-3px` won't work because it deals with positioning. More than likely you probably need to use `padding-top:-3px;`. If that doesn't, we'd need to see code because it is impossible to answer by looking at a picture

Comment: Negative padding does not work. It would have to be margin, which has other problems.

Comment: Why cant you just wait until the OP responds with a clarified question ?

Comment: `position:relative;top:-3px;` would be a better option imo although the best option is waiting on the code example lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
line-height: 0
```

And adjust the margin-top: value.
Or a lower line-height value. (e.g., 1em line-height would be relative to the font-size as 1:1em)

Sicking to px in this scenario is your best bet for cross browser consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it's going to be hard to identify the exact issue, but lets give it a shot.

All text has something called `line-height` which is the amount of space from the top of the font to the bottom of the font. Most fonts build in padding along the top to make multiple lines of text readable. CSS allows us to adjust that.

```
p {
   line-height: 14px;
}
```

This code will tell all `<p>` elements to have a total `line-height` of `14px`. If your font is taller than `14px` it will overlap.

If this doesn't fix your problem, then the issue probably has to do with the margin/padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.medium-title {
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 0.8;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fx314qhh/1/

Comment: But will it work on all mobile devices when you hardcode it like that?

Comment: You'll have to test it on mobile devices, but font-size is already hardcoded to 17px, isn't it? You can always add `@media` query to set different `line-height` on mobile devices.